# How to use specs2 to assert a Date is equal to another Date if their difference is less than 1 second?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, specs2

I'm writing a specs2 test, and need to compare two dates:

```
import java.util.Date

val date1: Date = getDate1();
val date2: Date = getDate2();

date1 must beEqualToAnotherDate(date2, 1.second)
```

There is no such `beEqualToAnotherDate` matcher, how can I do the same in specs2 efficiently?

Comment: Which equality criterias? Why not `mustEqual`?

Comment: `date1` and `date2` may not be equal, say if date1 is `2011-11-11 10:10:10 111` and date2 is `2011-11-11 10:10:10 888`, I still consider they are equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a custom matcher, you can try something like:

```scala
import java.util.Date

import org.specs2.matcher.{
  Expectable,
  Matcher,
  MatchResult,
  MatchersImplicits,
  Specification
}

object MySpecs extends Specification with MatchersImplicits {

  def beCloseInTimeTo(date: Date, timeDiff: Int) = new Matcher[Date] {
    def apply[D <: Date](e: Expectable[D]) = 
      result((e.value.getTime - date.getTime) < timeDiff,
        "Dates are nearly at the same time",
        "Dates are different",
        e)
  }

  dateA must beCloseInTimeTo(dateB, timeInMillis)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use *must beBetween*:

```
val millis = date2.getTime()

date1.getTime() must beBetween(millis - 500, millis + 500)
```